# keras:You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,224,224,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model summary doesn't indicate the presence of 'input_1' however, when I try to run the code, it displays an error as shown. I'm new to keras and I'm stuck on this . Can you provide me a direction?

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,224,224,3]
 [[Node: input_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,224,224,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

[This html file contains a jupyter notebook of my code with the error which is mentioned above .](https://github.com/Rverma28/hello-world/blob/master/DeepRankingModelVGG19-Copy2.html)

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should know that without Eager, tensorflow is a static model, which means that you should build the model first and feed value for your model. It seems that you create a placeholder at first and you just run you model without feeding value for your placeholder. I believe that you should feed [self.batch_size, 224, 224, 3] for your placeholder.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the suggestion. For convenience i have added the full python code as html file . Can you please go through it and suggest some ways to handle that ?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. What's the solution?